# Scala: List drop first n empty items

Tags: scala, collections

I have a List:

```
val arr = Array("", "", "a", "b", "")
```

I want to apply a method on `arr`, such that my output is:

```
Array("a", "b", "")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just

```
arr.dropWhile(_.isEmpty)
```